# Add to cart issue - Magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, addtocart, ajax

In Magento 2.1 When I enable Ajax on add to cart on Product detailed Page by `"bindSubmit": true` in `add-to-cart.phtml`

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "catalogAddToCart": {
                "bindSubmit": false
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "catalogAddToCart": {
                "bindSubmit": true
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Now after clearing cache, I added a simple product to cart which was perfect, but on product with Option(Configurable option) when I add to cart without selecting the option, It show error "*This is a required field.*", but the ajax starts already and refresh the page giving error "*Please specify product's required option(s).*". Meaning Ajax add to cart don't wait for me to select the option, when I do not select option.

Hope you understand, what I am trying to say.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should add more validation:

*vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js*

```
_bindSubmit: function() {
            var self = this;
            this.element.mage('validation');
            this.element.on('submit', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                if(self.element.valid()) {
                    self.submitForm($(this));
                }
            });
        },
```

See more [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/5854).